# Make prettier less uglier - prevent split tags

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

[Prettier](https://prettier.io/) in VS Code is great, except in this case where it seems to make things less readable. Here's an example of prettier's wrapping behavior in a Vue template file:

[image]

Notice the opening tag's end bracket is placed as start of second line, and closing tag is split between end of line 2 and 3. In my mind, this is more pretty:

[image]

Now the tags are complete on their own lines and the content is alone on line 2.

I've been unable to find a way to configure this in the prettier docs. Any ninjas know how?

Comment: Your second example adds leading and trailing whitespace to the tag's `textContent`. Are you sure that's desirable in all cases?

Comment: Yes, in my case it hasn't caused any problems, so I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try to set `htmlWhitespaceSensitivity` property to `ignore` in your prettier config.

Comment: That was the cause of the behavior I was wanting to avoid, thanks.

Comment: Superb, i went through every solution provided on google but this one only worked for me. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

I agree your opinion. This Linter rule will help you.

[eslint-plugin-vue/html-closing-bracket-newline.md at master · vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/html-closing-bracket-newline.md)

I setting up rules in `.eslintrc.js` below.

```
"vue/html-closing-bracket-newline": [2, { multiline: "never" }]
```

and I setting up `.vscode/setting.json` below

```
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm referring to a prettier auto-formatting behavior, not a linter warning. I believe these are separate.

Comment: Sorry I added `.vscode/setting.json`. I use `eslint --fix` on save instead of VS Code prettier

Comment: The question is about how to configure prettier's formatting, not about using linting instead.